# Open shell from find-file interactively

Tags: tramp, shell, find-file

Currently, I can use `C-x C-f` to `find-file` (or `ido-find-file`) then open a dired directory and launch `M-x shell`.
[image]

Is it possible to interactively navigate a path be it a local `~/Documents` or tramp shell `/ssh:server:Documents` and immediately create shell instance on that directory similar to above workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workflow for [embark](https://github.com/oantolin/embark).

```lisp
(defun open-shell-in-directory (directory &rest rest)
  (interactive "D")
  ;; If default-directory is a remote directory, make sure we find its
  ;; delete-directory handler.
  (setq directory (directory-file-name (expand-file-name directory)))
  (let ((default-directory directory))
    (shell)))
```

and bind this function to `embark-file-map` with the key you like.

now you can navigate to some directory, `embark-action` and press the key you defined or just `M-x open-shell-in-directory`.

Comment: Do you if there is a map for ido-find-file similar to `embark-file-map`? If I am navigating with `ido-find-file` (without opening file or dired) and call `embark-act` I get `Act on nil ''`. Slowly reading docs if it's possible to do so.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if embark can be combined with ido. Just showing a workflow to see if you can learn from it.